Heroku Postgres database error: "server does not support SSL, but SSL was required"
I am trying to enable pgbouncer to experiment with managing number of connections to my app.
I followed this guide, but am seeing the following error when the app hits the database.
connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 6000 failed: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required

My Procfile is as follows:
web: bin/start-pgbouncer-stunnel gunicorn backend.wsgi
release: python manage.py migrate

The error does not appear when I omit the bin/start-pgbouncer-stunnel part
In settings.py, I have my DATABASES variable configured like this:
if env.get("DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT"):
    DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
            "OPTIONS": {
                "service": env.get("DATABASE_SERVICE"),
            },
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        "default": dj_database_url.config(
            conn_max_age=500, ssl_require=True
        )
    }

However, I notice that the error page lists the DATABASES variable, and this includes sslmode': 'require:
DATABASES   
{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
             'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
             'CONN_HEALTH_CHECKS': False,
             'CONN_MAX_AGE': 600,
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
             'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
             'NAME': 'db1',
             'OPTIONS': {'sslmode': 'require'},
             'PASSWORD': '********************',
             'PORT': 6000,
             'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                      'COLLATION': None,
                      'MIGRATE': True,
                      'MIRROR': None,
                      'NAME': None},
             'TIME_ZONE': None,
             'USER': 'zvchpwwqszbgax'}}

Have I configured something incorrectly? I assume that Heroku enables SSL for the attached Postgres database, and see it as "required" seems like the correct setting is enabled.

You need to enable SSL in pgBouncer. That means setting client_tls_sslmode to allow or require.

Thanks — looking at the docs, I have 2 follow-up questions. 1) It seems like enabling client_tls_sslmode requires specifying keys. My assumption based on limited knowledge is that this is usually automatically handled by Heroku. Any idea how this is handled? 2) Where does the pgbouncer.ini file go for a Heroku app? Understood these are specific to Heroku, not necessary pgbouncer

Good questions that I cannot answer, since I don't know Heroku. I can only point out the technical cause of the problem. You are right, you need server certificates.
